# CSng() or x 1F?

Tags: vb.net

Suppose option `Strict On`;  `a` and `b` - Integers

```
Dim mySingle as Single = a / b  ' implicit conversion error
```

Solution **A)**

```
Dim mySingle as Single = CSng(a / b)  ' CSng
```

Solution **B)**

```
Dim mySingle as Single = a * 1F / b  ' x 1F
```

What solution is preferable?
What solution to take if *performance* is important?

Comment: Solution A may throw you off if you ever switch to C# (because in C#, `int / int` returns an `int`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For readability and revealing intent, I would go with A:

```
Dim mySingle as Single = CSng(a / b)  ' CSng
```

Using A, you are clearly saying, I know the calculation returns a different type and that's what I want.

As for performance - I ran a quick micro-benchmark testing 1 million iterations for each and the difference was in the millisecond to sub-millisecond level, with a very slight advantage to `CSing`. Don't worry about performance for this kind of conversions (of course, you need to test this on your own).

Benchmark code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim mySingle As Single
    Dim a As Integer = 10
    Dim b As Integer = 5

    Dim iterations As Integer = 1000000

    Dim sw As New Stopwatch()

    sw.Start()
    For i As Integer = 1 To iterations
        mySingle = CSng(a / b)  ' CSng '
    Next
    sw.Stop()

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("CSng(a / b) - {0}", sw.Elapsed))


    sw.Reset()
    sw.Start()
    For i As Integer = 1 To iterations
        mySingle = a * 1.0F / b  ' x 1F '
    Next
    sw.Stop()

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" a * 1.0F / b - {0}", sw.Elapsed))

End Sub
```

Comment: You never stated performance being an issue. Perhaps you should revise your question.

Comment: surely this could be other solution like CSng(a) / b  etc :)